# open saveas dialog box and input file name from a specific cell while with excel doc forcing the file type to xlsm

Tags: excel, vbscript

Im looking for the correct VB code to open saveas dialog box and input file name from a specific cell "A1" within an excel doc forcing the file type to xlsm

Comment: Welcome to SO. Here we don't just provide code, but answers to questions. What is the part you are having problems with? Have you tried invoking `Application.GetSaveAsFilename`? did you pay attention to its `InitialFileName` and `FilterIndex` parameters?

Comment: Great stuff, i have various codes on the go but struggle to get the save element to works. since my original request i have slightly changed the requirement. i want to use the same saveas path as the original document wherever that may be but still forcing the xlsm extension. i have been trying various combinations to no avail.i have been using the following for the filename "NewFileName = Range("a1").Value"

Comment: ive been using the following but it seems to default to documents                                                                                                                                      Sub SaveToRelativePath()
    Dim relativePath As String
    relativePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Range("a1").Value
    End Sub

Comment: instead of appending comments, edit your question posting the relevant code of your attempts